# Kendo for MVC: How to ensure window content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo for MVC and I have a kendo window as followed:

```cshtml
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Draggable(false)
        .Animation(a => a.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)).Close(close => close.Fade(FadeDirection.Out)))
        .Events(e => e.Activate("..."))
        .Visible(false)
        .Position(p => p.Top(0).Left(100))
        .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
        .Content(c => Html.Partial("~/Views/Popup/CreateView.cshtml"))     
)
```

The window is initially invisible, and the content is loaded from a partial view using `.Content`

What I am trying to do is once the content DOM is loaded, do some custom thing via JavaScript.

I have tried to call those JavaScript functions in the page's `$(document).ready()` but it gives an error which indicates the DOM of the window is not ready yet. When I set timeout of 5 seconds, the script works perfectly, but I guess this is not a good solution.

Thus my question is, is there any event, or any method that Kendo provides to ensure the content of the window is ready? (So that I can call my JavaScript in that callback function)

Comment: Maybe this, I think. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-refresh

Comment: @wannadream no, because that is only fired if you use AJAX to load the content, here it is loading static page directly

Comment: Perhaps take a look into [deferring script initialisation](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferring)